# How to assign a random number to every element = 1 in my 3D list?

Tags: list, 3d, python-3.7

I have created a 3D list called x and I have created another list with the same size as my previous list called y with zero elements. I need to loop through my x list and check if every element is equal to 1, give it a random number in my y list. My try is below, but I got an error:

```
import random
import numpy as np

x =   [[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]],
        [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]]

y = [[[0 for row in range(len(x[0][0]))] for col in range(len(x[0]))] for a in range(len(x))]
for i in range(len(x[0][0])):    
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        for k in range(len(x)):

            if x[i][j][k] == 1:
                y[i][j][k] = random.randint(1,100)

            else:
                y[i][j][k] = 0

print(y)
```

The error:

```
if grid[i][j][k] == 1:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could I get any assistance please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the looping the wrong way round.

You always want to loop the outmost list first and proceed inwards for each element in the respective outer list.

Try it like this:

```
for i in range(len(x)):    
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        for k in range(len(x[0][0])):

            if x[i][j][k] == 1:
                y[i][j][k] = random.randint(1,100)

            else:
                y[i][j][k] = 0
```

Comment: No problem. Would be charming, if you accepted my answer.

Comment: Yes dear. I'm accepting the answer, but it gave me a notice to wait four minutes. After these four minutes, I will do it.